# Changing the Line Ending from Unix/Linux to Windows from terminal

Tags: windows, linux, conversion, newlines

I have a bunch of text files created in Ubuntu and when I access them on a Windows machine using DropBox they are not properly formatted because of the `Line Ending` difference between Unix/Linux and Windows.

After changing the Line Ending from Unix/Linux to Windows, the text file was rendered properly in both Windows and Ubuntu.

How to convert the Line Ending from terminal to automate the conversion?

Comment: Most text editors in Windows can handle Unix line breaks, notepad.exe being the notable exception (even Wordpad can).

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu:

```
$ apt-get install dos2unix
$ unix2dos file.txt
```

On Windows:

- Download and extract dos2unix from http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html (the Windows 32-bit version or the Windows 64-bit version)
- On the command prompt, enter `dos2unix-<something>\bin\unix2dos.exe file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the `tofrodos` package.  Converts neatly either way, with `todos` and `fromdos`.  Available only on the Ubuntu side, I should note.

On the Windows side, my memory is that Wordpad (unlike Notepad) will in fact display files with *nix line endings correctly, which should be a help for viewing files that haven't been converted.